# loop for each class ends with number using js

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

What I have is something like the following, what I want is loop for each card ends with a number like card1 to to access its card-content class to hide it when I hover the a tag, in short I want when I hover each a tag its card-content class will be hided using pure js, any help would be appreciate...

```
<div class="cards">
    <a href="" class="card card1">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" class="card card2">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="" class="card card3">
        <div class="card-content">
            <h2>heading</h2>
            <p>paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want cofee or tea while we prepare the code for you ?

Comment: why not just use css to hide the child on hover?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif I'm newbie in js, I know the basics of looping and I tried someways but failed, I didn't ask for preparing the code read the question properly , I said any help would be appreciate

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I have a lot of classes like that, I think I need to specify each class in css if I do something like this

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do it hide a child div on hover of the parent you can use simple css as such

```
<!--html-->
<div class="cards">
  <a href="" class="card card1">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="card card2">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>


// css
.card-content {
  display: block;
}
.card:hover .card-content {
  display: none;
}
```

If however it is something where the divs are not nested you might need js
such (the below is a bad example and should be avoided. Using css for manipulating the div on events such as hover is always better)

```
<!--html-->
<div class="cards">
  <a href="" class="card card1">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="card card2">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2>heading</h2>
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="btn1">Hide card1</button>
  <button class="btn2">Hide card2</button>
</div>


//javascript (jQuery)
$('[class^="btn"]').on('hover', function(event) {
    selector = '.' + event.target.className.replace('btn', 'card');
    console.log(selector);  // will log "card1" or "card2" depending on which button you hover over
    $(selector).hide()
});
// similar code to then show the element
```

A better approach compared to using incremented classes is to have just a single class, and data attributes instead

```
<div class="card" data-card-id="1"></div>
```

You can then easily use jQuery to lookup using the data attributes as needed

```
$('.card[data-card-id="1"]')
```

Comment: not exactly what I needed , but still got some ideas, hover didn't worked so that I changed the event to mouseover instead, thank you so much.

Comment: Always happy to help :)